# How to print something when a character touches a character

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, c++

I am making a stickman rush game, where it goes up and down and then there is a object that scrolls to the left. Whenever that stickman touches the object, it prints game over. However when the object is below the stickman, it prints game over even though its not touching. Can someone explain why this is happening?

Code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>


LiquidCrystal lcd(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);

byte customChar[] = {
  B01110,
  B01110,
  B01110,
  B00100,
  B01110,
  B10101,
  B00100,
  B01010
};

byte gameObstical[] = {
  B11111,
  B11111,
  B11111,
  B11111,
  B11111,
  B11111,
  B11111,
  B11111
};



int vX = A0;
int vY = A1;
int sw = 8;

int xPosition = 0;
int yPosition = 0;
int SW_state = 0;
int mapX = 0;
int mapY = 0;

int screenWidth = 16;
int screenHeight = 2;


void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(vX, INPUT);
  pinMode(vY, INPUT);
  pinMode(sw, INPUT);


   lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.createChar(0, customChar);
  lcd.home();
  lcd.write(byte(0));

  lcd.createChar(1, gameObstical);
  lcd.write(byte(1));

}

void loop() {

  int stickManPosition = 0;
  int obsticalPosition = 0;
  int stickManPosition2 = 0;
  int obsticalPosition2 = 0;
  
  for (obsticalPosition = 15; obsticalPosition >= 0; obsticalPosition--) {
  lcd.setCursor(obsticalPosition, 1);
  lcd.write(byte(1));
  lcd.print(" ");
  delay(150);


  
  xPosition = analogRead(vX);
  yPosition = analogRead(vY);
  SW_state = digitalRead(sw);
  mapX = map(xPosition, 20, 1003, -500, 500);

    Serial.println("-----------");
  Serial.println(mapX);
  Serial.println("-----------");

  

    if (mapX > 200) {
    
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(stickManPosition, 0);
    lcd.write(byte(0));
    
  } else if (mapX < -200) {

    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(stickManPosition, 1);
    lcd.write(byte(0));
    }
    
  if (stickManPosition == obsticalPosition) {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Game Over.");
      } else if (
    }
  }
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Your code says to print Game Over if `stickManPosition == obsticalPosition`, so it is doing exactly that. You need to save what row the stick and obstacles are on and compare that too.

Comment: I dont know how to do that.. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

You check StickMan and Object only X position not check Y position
incase you can check StickMan Y or check StickMan action like this code below.
or try this sim https://www.tinkercad.com/things/1LiyoY5n1mS-copy-of-stickman-rush/editel?sharecode=X6rMj1GjrKoAH95qWKY21z98ttyAs5aOTAKYy6hVJ3c

```
// Defind it on top
bool stickManIsJump = false; 

// Added some code to check StickMan isJump or not
if (mapX > 200) {
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(stickManPosition, 0);
  stickManIsJump = true;        /////////////// ADDED
  lcd.write(byte(0));
} else if (mapX < -200) {
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(stickManPosition, 1);
  stickManIsJump = false;       /////////////// ADDED
  lcd.write(byte(0));
}

if (stickManPosition == obsticalPosition && !stickManIsJump) {      /////////////// ADDED
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Game Over.");
}
```

[image]